# Perl: Getting difference between two arrays of hashes?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have two array references that contain hashes:

```
$A = [
  {
    "t" => "1419054300000",
    "v" => "28.1"
  },
  {
    "t" => "1419053400000",
    "v" => "28.2"
  },
  {
    "t" => "1419052500000",
    "v" => "28.4"
  }
];

$B = [
  {
    "t" => "1419053400000",
    "v" => "28.2"
  },
  {
    "t" => "1419052500000",
    "v" => "28.4"
  }
];
```

I want to get *only* the hashes from `$A` where their value of `t` doesn't already exist in one of the hashes in `$B` (the `t` values are unique per arrayref, `v` isn't).

I assume there's some obvious method of doing this, but I've been banging my head against this all day without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [perl5i `diff` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5i#diff).

```
use perl5i::2;

...initialize $A and $B...

say $A->diff($B)->mo->as_perl;
__END__
[
  {
    't' => '1419054300000',
    'v' => '28.1'
  }
]
```

Comment: I had no idea about perl5i! Thanks very much, that works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

As always you can build hash look up where keys are elements you want to filter out,

```
my %seen;
@seen{ map $_->{t}, @$B } = ();

my $C = [
  grep { !exists $seen{$_->{t}} } @$A
];
```